# Articles of Casnati on algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, paper-request

I am attempting to track down online copies of the following two algebraic geometry articles.

Is there some repository where these might be found?  If necessary I could use the first few pages of each article, or maybe even just the first page if a preview is available.

Casnati, Gianfranco, and Torsten Ekedahl. "Covers of algebraic varieties I. A general structure theorem, covers of degree 3, 4 and Enriques surfaces." Journal of Algebraic Geometry 5, no. 3 (1996): 439-460.

Casnati, Gianfranco. "Covers of algebraic varieties II. Covers of degree 5 and construction of surfaces." Journal of Algebraic Geometry 5, no. 3 (1996): 461-478.

Comment: Have you tried to contact the author? Here is a link to his webpage https://staff.polito.it/gianfranco.casnati/

Comment: OK, I will try this, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Have you found these two papers? I cannot find them too

Comment: @JiabinDu The papers are not in my records so I must have given up trying to find them.  I think you could try contacting the author using the webpage above.

Comment: @HollisWilliams Ok, I will contact the author directly. Thank you!